# Regarding List and map

Tags: apex, list, map

I need to create a List of accounts.
Query all account records and store them in the list.
Write a for loop on that list and
pass values one by one into a map.

Comment: Great! So you don't want to try yourself. If we give you the solution for this how will you solve your other tasks without knowing concepts. Anyways welcome to Stackexchange please read this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask when you want your next tasks to be done by us.

Answer (score 4):

Have you reviewed any documentation in order to do that? There are thousand of places with code examples.

Also, you should specify what you really need. What kind of values do you need in the map? In any case these are my 2 options:

1- Get a list and pass to a map

```
 List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
 accounts = [Select Id, Name From Account]; //Add all fields you need

 Map<Id, Account> accountsMap = new Map<Id, Account>();
 for(Account acc : accounts)
 {
      accountsMap.put(acc.Id, acc);
 }
```

2- Above option in a single step

```
 Map<Id, Account> accountsMap = new Map<Id, Account> ([Select Id, Name From Account]); //Add all your fields in the query
```

Find [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.192.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_maps.htm) more information about maps